# Passing a date in an exiftool command

Tags: command-line, bash, date, exiftool

I am writing a bash script and want to get the date after every week. Is it possible?

My command

```
exiftool -exififd:dateTimeOriginal="2008:10:23 00" test.jpg
```

So instead of 2008:10:23, I want to pass a date value then run a while loop to batch process files

Comment: Could you please include an example? I don't understand what you want or how weeks are connected to it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you for help but my problem got solved already ,i wanted to run a while loop that displays the date of next n number of sunday

Comment: @DavidFoerster if possible you can delete the post , i got my answer from other post i made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use bash expression `$(command)` for command substitution as below within your command and format the date bar on your expectations.

```
exiftool -exififd:dateTimeOriginal="$(date + "%y:%m:%d") 00" test.jpg
```

Comment: Thnx i edit my script accordingly

Comment: Can you help me with this https://github.com/Guilty-King/Scripts/blob/master/exif_batch i want to ep variable to display output as 01 instead of 1

Comment: thanks, you can print it out or set with printf command like 'temp=$(printf %01d $ep)'